# Updating multiple records using Laravel 5.3 model binding

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am pulling multiple records from MySQL and looping through model binding and filling all the input fields with some data.

Now, I may change 2 or 10 or all 26 fields and hit update button. I want to update all the records. Now, I don't know how $id works here? usually I update single record and I have $id which I can find and update only that field.
But that's not the case here. I am pulling 13 records(or 26 fields). 13 field_1 and 13 field_2. How to update all?

## mycode

**Database**

```
Table
-id
-name
-field1 (updating this one)
-field2 (updating this one)
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/cat' , 'AdminController@cat');
Route::patch('/cat/{$id}/update','AdminController@cat_update');
```

**Controller**

```
public function cat(){

        $cattfs = Catf::all();
        return view('/cat',compact('cattfs'));
}

public function cat_update(Request $request, $id) // id = 1
{
        $rules = array(
            'field1'              => 'required',
            'field2'              => 'required'
          );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {

             return Redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);

        } else {

            $cat = Cattf::find($id); //This wont work :/
            $cat ->field1  = Input::get('field1');
            $cat ->field2  = Input::get('field2');
            $cat ->save();

        return redirect('/cat');
        }
}
```

**Views**

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:#fff">

    <table class="table table-hover">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center">Product</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Pr</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Co</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     @foreach ($cattos as $catto)
    {!! Form::model($catto,[ 'method' =>'PATCH', 'url' => ['/cat/.$catto->id./update']]) !!}

      <tr>
        <td>{{$catto->name}}</td>
          <td>    {!! Form::text('field1' ,null  ,  ['class'=>'form-control'])  !!}</td>
        <td>      {!! Form::text('field2' ,null  ,  ['class'=>'form-control'])  !!}</td>
      </tr>

      @endforeach

     <td colspan="3">
     {!! Form::submit('UPDATE', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-block']) !!}
      {!! Form::close() !!}
      </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  </div>
```

**snapshot of the form**

[image: fields snapshot each row is a record from database table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with Model binding (correct me if I'm wrong someone).

What you can instead do is generate an array of data to post to your controller.

For example:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'catupdate']) !!}
    @foreach ($cattos as $catto)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$catto->name}}</td>
            <td>{!! Form::text('categories['.$catto->id.'][field1]', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</td>
            <td>{!! Form::text('categories['.$catto->id.'][field2]', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

You should then receive an array in your controller, which you can loop around and update each record.

```
public function catupdate()
{
    $categories = request()->input('categories');

    foreach($categories as $id => $values) {
        $cat = Cattf::find($id); 
        $cat->field1 = $values['field1'];
        $cat->field2 = $values['field2'];
        $cat->save();
    }
}
```

You can then also validate the array by doing the following in your Request file

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'categories.*.field1' => 'required',
        'categories.*.field2' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

**this is untested and is an example demonstrating the concept**

Comment: is binding still possible, that is to show what previous values in database are?